# Populating inner table inside another table with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have DTO class:

```
private LocalDate date;
private List<String> firstShift;
private List<String> secondShift;
private List<String> thirdShift;
```

With getters, setters and toString for every field.

I'm creating this table for shift schedule calendar:

[image]

My Thymeleaf:

```
    <table class = "table table-striped table-hover" id = "schedule_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class = "th_schedule_table">Date</th>
                <th class = "th_schedule_table">First Shift</th>
                <th class = "th_schedule_table">Second Shift</th>
                <th class = "th_schedule_table">Third Shift</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each = "calendar_node : ${calendarNodeList}">
                <td th:text = "${calendar_node.date}"></td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each = "employee, i : ${firstShift}">
                                <td th:text = "${firstShift.[i]}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each = "employee: ${secondShift}">
                                <td th:text = "${employee}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The idea behind this: CalendarNode.date generates row for parent table, for each date. That works fine.

Inside every row, in a cell I have second table that should show list of employees who works on that date in that shift. If I have calendar_node object in one row, I'm using his "firstShift" field to generated rows for second inner table.

The problem is that I'm getting empty table. I checked my back-end and I have two employees for first date (18th July), first shift, one employee for second shift, but none is shown. I tried a lot of different syntax for Thymeleaf, none of it works. I guess I did Thymeleaf wrong?

UPDATE:
Example of data that has been passed to web page via model object:

[image]

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible example with the exact attributes that you are passing to Thymeleaf with some example data? What is see on first sight is that you probably want to get the list of employee names per shift from the `calendar_node` variable instead of accessing `firstShift` and `secondShift` which are not changing per row/node.

Comment: @Matt I updated now, I hope it will help you.
firstShift is a field of calendar_node. firstShift is of type List<String> you can see in DTO. Thanks for helping

Comment: What I meant is code that can be copy and pasted in an IDE to reproduce the problem. A screenshot is not that much helpful.

Comment: If `firstShift` is a field of `calendar_node`, then you need to actually address it as such in the template: `${calendar_node.firstShift}` instead of `${firstShift}`.

Comment: It works now! The reason why I wrote ${firstShift} before instead of ${calendar_node.firstShift} is because I had Thymeleaf error, and other post from Stackoverlow said to write like this. Maybe I missunderstood or wrote something wrong entirely.
You can post this comment as an answer so I can accept it, I can give you some points! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `firstShift` is a field of `calendar_node`, then you need to actually address it as such in the template:

`${calendar_node.firstShift}` instead of `${firstShift}`